# adding a responsive iframe div class to a 3 column floating div layout

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am a newbie so my apologies up front!  I am working in a CMS for my company and I'm trying to use  tags instead of tables to align content so it works well with our adaptive mobile site.

I am trying to embed a youtube video within a 3 div/column layout. I can get 3 divs across using a float with percentange width to work correctly and I can get a youtube embed to act responsively on it's own page....but I can't combine the two.  I know I have a conflict somewhere.  Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .embed-box {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 62.25%;
    /* ratio for youtube embed */ padding-top: 30px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .embed-box iframe, .embed-box object, .embed-box embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style><span style="font-size:18px;"><strong>Lehigh Athletics Department Awards and Achievements</strong></span>
<hr /> <span style="font-size:16px;"><strong>Highlights of 2013-2014 Convocation</strong></span>
<div class="bottom">
  <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
    <img style="" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/5/6/ProgramIcon.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="embed-box">
    <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
      <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zQmxGbFbgXc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
    <img style="" src="/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=0&amp;image_path=/images/2014/5/6/ProgramIcon.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this layout a try. I rewrote your CSS and HTML. You had too much inline stuff that just wasn't working for me. This is responsive and contains the Youtube embed.

**<kbd>[CodePen](http://codepen.io/webfrogs/pen/iyroa)</kbd>**

Comment: If the answer works for you, please mark it appropriately using the checkmark.

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately, it breaks when viewed on an iPhone.  The first two content areas are stacked (which is fine) but the third is missing completely.  Our site is adaptive...not truly responsive. Sometimes, a CMS is great...sometimes it isn't!

Comment: Was it built on a Bootstrap framework? Do you have a link to the site? It might be easier to debug from there.

Comment: I don't know if it uses Bootstrap - here's the url: http://lehighsports.com/sports/2014/5/7/test2.aspx  On the desktop browser, there is also a conflict with the header graphics when I add your code

Comment: You're using EKTRON... an asp.net CMS. That's a tough one. Have you tried looking through the content on http://www.ektron.com/, to see if they might be able to assist... they might have a quick fix or a Master Page/ Style sheet that's already equipped to deal with your issues.